# How to update a Div in your page from a JQuery Ui dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

How can I update my page from a JQuery UI dialog? this is is my code so far and is not working. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
function submit_new_site() {

    //these are the input text id's on the dialog 
    address = $('#loc_address').val();
    city = $('#loc_city').val();
    county = $('#loc_county').val();
    state = $('#loc_state').val();
    zip = $('#loc_zip').val();
    notes = $('#loc_notes').val();

    //and these are the div's on the page that calls the jQuery UI dialog
    $('#new_site').html(address);
    $('#new_site_city').html(city);
    $('#new_site_county').html(county);
    $('#new_site_state').html(state);
    $('#new_site_zip').html(zip);

    //this function is called from a button on the jQuery UI dialog
    //but is not updating the page with the user entered information.       

}
```

Comment: More code please. Where are these lines executed?

Comment: Seeing the code on jsFiddle would be helpful.  What's not working?

Comment: That should work just fine -- assuming those id's are really unique

Answer (score 0):

try `$('#loc_address').prop('value')` instead. `val()` no longer always reports the current value, IIRC.

Comment: thanks mathletics but it was really stupid mistake from my part. forgot to update the id names in the page... thanks